# design pattern for invoke constructor

Tags: java, design-patterns, constructor

I have an object with two different constructors:

```
public class MyClass {
   public MyClass(arg1, arg2) {
       //constructor
   }

   public MyClass() {};

}
```

I need to invoke the second one only by a specific class of my software (the first one could be invoked anywhere). Is there a design pattern specific for this case?

`MyClass` and the invoking class are in two different packages, so a package-private constructor is not a solution.

Comment: There might be a design smell here. The need for 2 different constructors might indicate it's actually not the same object you want to manipulate in the two packages, or maybe you need a third, more execution context-aware object to instantiate `MyClass` with relevant arg1 and arg2 and pass it to package1 or package 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without design pattern it can be done in one way. Set one constructor public, which will be invoked from all class. And the other declare it package private. Now place this class and the specific on in the same package.

```
public class MyClass {
   public MyClass(arg1, arg2) {
       //constructor
   }

   MyClass() {};  // only for the class in the same package

}
```

So now the public constructor can be used from all while the package protected constructor can be invoked only by the class in the same package.

**Another Option**

You can use a different implementaion of factory pattern

```
public class MyClass {
   public MyClass(arg1, arg2) {
       //constructor
   }

   public MyClass() {}; 

}
```

And the factory

```
public class MyClassFactory{
    public static MyClass createMyClass(Object o){
        if (o instanceOf SpecificClass)
            return new MyClass();
        else
            return new MyClass(arg1,arg2);
    }
}
```

Now call like

```
MyClass mC = MyclassFactory.createMyClass(this);
```

N.B.. I just ommitted the arguments. You can pass the arguments in `createMyClass` method.

Comment: I know it, but i would invoke it from class inside another package (and i cant' move that class from his package :) )4

Comment: In *Another Option*, `public MyClass() {};` should be `package-private`.

Comment: yes, it works :) i've just modify your general purpose code for adapt it to my specific case. thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever seen your second pattern in the wild. Is this something you just invented?

Comment: @DuncanJones lol no .. it is not any common pattern... I just experiemented from the concept of factory.. Just some rougn codes here... Please suggest if you have better solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
public class Test {
    public Test() {
        StackTraceElement[] stack = new Throwable().getStackTrace();
        StackTraceElement topOfStack = stack[0];
        if (!topOfStack.getClassName().equals("mypackage.MyClass"))
            throw new SecurityException("Haha! You are not allowed to call me!");
        // ....
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test(); // Haha! You are not allowed to call me!
    }
}
```